# How to delete email messages from Spotlight search on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, spotlight

I have a iPhone 4S running iOS 6. Spotlight seems to find deleted e-mails on iPhone, how can I delete e-mails permanently from Spotlight results?

Could this potentially be a bug in iOS 6? I am thinking it sounds like a bug.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: So, other then Spotlight, you cannot find the email on your phone? If you tap the Spotlight result, does it bring you to the message? If you are using a service such as Gmail are you possibly archiving the messages and not actually permanently deleting?

Comment: So as you mentioned I have been using hotmail as e-mail service and if I tap Spotlight search then I should be seeing deleted e-mail messages.

Comment: I am trying to understand your situation. I'm afraid I don't understand what exactly you were saying in the comment (other then that you use Hotmail). So you *do* want to see deleted messages? Maybe you could try answering some of the questions in my comment above?

Comment: Are you sure you are deleting your mails and not archiving them ?

Comment: @bassplayer7 - as you said I don't want to see deleted messages from spotlight search. I hope I have been enough clear.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - I'm definitely sure.

Comment: Can you find the offending messages within a "Trash" or "Deleted Items" folder in the Mail.app? If so empty your trash. It should be searching all Mail or no Mail, regardless of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

i have just hopefully cured my problem - delete all the stuff you want gone, go backup your device, then go to delete all data and settings on your fone and choose restore from back up - then your device should be as it was but without the old deleted data saved

Answer (score -1):

From what I have read there is no current way to permanently delete the cache from the iPhone, but the best thing you can do is go to *Settings » General » Spotlight Search* and from here deactivate Mail so that the e-mails don't show up in Spotlight search.

I strongly hope that Apple adds a option to clear the cache on their devices.